# IF END IF IN SQL STORED PROCEDURE

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a advanced search query in which user's name,status and role are filtered at the same time (one or more can be selected).
Given below is the code for the SQL Stored Procedure
I want a way to have IF and END IF, so that the where condition in all the cases are mutually exclusive
Currently if the first name is null, then the rest of the conditions fail

```
USE [qcsl]
GO
/***** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UserAdvancedSearch]    Script Date: 3/31/2017 3:25:28 PM *****/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:        Mayank
-- Create date: 2017-03-29
-- Description:   
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserAdvancedSearch]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
  (
    @user_name varchar(50) = NULL,
    @user_last_name varchar(50) = NULL,
    @role_id varchar(50) = NULL,
    @user_status varchar(50) = NULL,
    @query varchar(2000) = NULL output
  )
  AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

    SET @query = 'select * from user_main
    where 
    'IF (@user_name is not null ) SET @query = @query + '
    (user_first_name like '''+@user_name+''' OR user_first_name IS NULL)
    'IF (@user_last_name is not null ) SET @query = @query + 'AND
    (user_last_name like '''+@user_last_name+''' OR user_last_name IS NULL)
    'IF (@user_status is not null ) SET @query = @query + 'AND
    (user_status = '+@user_status+') 'IF (@role_id is not null) SET @query = @query + '
    AND
    (user_role_id_ref = '+@role_id+')'
    EXEC(@query);
END
```

Comment: What DBMS is this? This doesn't at all look like Oracle's PL/SQL. Please change your tags accordingly.

Comment: This is stored procedure in asp.net and i am using SQL Server RDBMS

Comment: The stored procedure is not asp.net, but MSSQL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If MSSQL db and if I understood you question, I think you could write:

(mutually esclusive):

```
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM USER_MAIN WHERE '
IF (@user_name is not null ) SET @query = @query + '(user_first_name like '''+@user_name+''' OR user_first_name IS NULL)'
ELSE IF (@user_last_name is not null ) SET @query = @query + ' (user_last_name like '''+@user_last_name+''' OR user_last_name IS NULL)'
ELSE IF (@user_status is not null ) SET @query = @query + ' (user_status = '+@user_status+') '
ELSE IF (@role_id is not null) SET @query = @query + ' (user_role_id_ref = '+@role_id+')'
```

**Edit**: instead if you want all together:

```
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM USER_MAIN WHERE 1=1 '
IF (@user_name is not null ) SET @query = @query + 'AND (user_first_name like '''+@user_name+''' OR user_first_name IS NULL)'
IF (@user_last_name is not null ) SET @query = @query + 'AND (user_last_name like '''+@user_last_name+''' OR user_last_name IS NULL)'
IF (@user_status is not null ) SET @query = @query + 'AND (user_status = '+@user_status+') '
IF (@role_id is not null) SET @query = @query + 'AND (user_role_id_ref = '+@role_id+')'
```

Comment: That won't solve the issue as if the first IF condition is a success then the other conditions won't be checked. But in my case, I want multiple conditions to be checked

Comment: If the first condition fails (user_name) in this case, then the rest of the conditions would not be checked

Comment: Are you speaking of my "edit" (second part of answer)?

Comment: Yes, i am talking about the second part, it is close to what I need, but in top-down order if any if condition fails, rest of the conditions would be ignored

Comment: No, I don't think so.  Try for example:  `DECLARE @A VARCHAR(1)='D'  ;
  IF @A='A' SELECT 1; 
  IF 'B'='B' SELECT 2;
  IF 'C'='C' SELECT 3;
  IF 'D'='D' SELECT 4;`

Comment: Thanks a lot.You saved my job!

Comment: Happy for this... I hope that someOne will save mine :-)